# How to use custom woff2 and oft fonts with Sphinx?

Tags: fonts, python-sphinx

I know you specify theme options with an object like :

```
html_theme_options = {'font_family':'Gotham','head_font_family':'Gotham Ultra'}
```

in conf.py. But sometimes browsers don't have access to such custom fonts like Gotham. Where do I put the custom font woff2 or otf file and how do I instruct Sphinx to use that for headers or for other fonts?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing so.

#### 1. Local override

First, you can override styles (and fonts by extension) locally. To achieve this, you would do:

1. Create `_static` directory in your Sphinx sources directory. Depending on whether you split in `source` and `build`, this typically is `docs/_static` or `docs/source/_static`.
2. In `_static/`, you create `styles.css` and save font files. Next, you define your fonts. E.g.:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: "Roboto Slab";
       src: url("./RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf");
   }
   ```

   And set the styles:

   ```
   body {
       font-family: "Roboto Slab";
   }
   ```

   Alternatively, you can just `@import` them from third-party:

   ```
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab');
   ```
3. In your Sphinx configuration (`conf.py`), you point Sphinx to your stylesheet:

   ```
   def setup(app):
       app.add_stylesheet('styles.css')
   ```

And that's it.

#### 2. Custom theme

Alternatively, you can create your own theme: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/theming.html.

Answer (score 1):

Most Sphinx themes don't have fonts as a configurable option. You would have to customize the theme by:

- editing the theme template to include the font file, either locally or remotely
- editing the theme's CSS to specify the font-face style
- optionally adding the static assets to the theme, if you load theme locally

See details of [templating](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html) in Sphinx.

Comment: can you give examples on editing the themes css or adding the font-face to the theme as a static asset? Would I basically fork something like alabaster (a common theme) and edit its css and use that as a custom theme?

Comment: Neither forking nor editing Alabaster theme files is necessary. You can override everything in the Alabaster theme by adding your own files. The link provided has details of how to do so, and explains it in a way that I would just copy-pasta here. So you might as well read it, try a few things, and come back with your result to share and any questions. You could also search for "[override Sphinx theme](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=override+Sphinx+theme)" for similar questions and answers. IOW, show some effort.